# How do I get notified when the user presses the Center on my Location button on the Google Maps v2 for Android API

Tags: android, google-maps

I can't find a way of being notified when the users presses this button that appears when `setMyLocationEnabled` is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps Android API v2 does not currently support this event.

See the code in **My Tracks** application, for how to create a workaround

https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/browse/MyTracks/src/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/fragments/MyTracksMapFragment.java

```
  /*
   * My Tracks needs to handle the onClick event when the my location button
   * is clicked. Currently, the API doesn't allow handling onClick event,
   * thus hiding the default my location button and providing our own.
   */
```